# How to skip Python 3.8.2 test of files encoding?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-3.8

I bumped into the following bug. When not all files are `utf-8` encodable, tests fail on `poetry run pytest -v`.

> ============================================================== ERRORS ===============================================================
> ____________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/anonymized/test.txt
> _____________________________________________ .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py/_path/common.py:171: in read_text
> return f.read() ../../../.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/codecs.py:322: in decode
> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) E   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in
> position 380: invalid start byte
> ====================================================== short test summary info ======================================================
> ERROR tests/anonymized/test.txt - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec
> can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 380: invalid start byte
> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error
> during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

In the meantime, exactly the same setup worked with Python 3.7, and if I run tests with `poetry run pytest tests/my_tests.py`.

I am using: Python 3.8.2, poetry 1.0.5

How can I fix it? This bug is annoying as it fails in CI.

Comment: Check the pytest, and remove relevant test. It seems that there is some incompatibility between (very) old UTF-8 (U as unversal, so UCS, which allow characters until 7FFF FFF) and new UTF-8 (U as Unicode, only to 10 FFFF), or change on the exception class. Very strange that you get the error, so it should be some "external" dependency/test which it is not up to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it came out, the issue was not related to any version of `poetry` or `python.` I named the file `test.txt` and put it under the `tests/` folder. By default, `pytest` finds all files prefixed with `test` and verifies their encoding. As the `test.txt` was in `iso-8859-1`, I got a UTF-8 related issue.

**NOTE:**

Make sure that you don't name files with the `test` prefix when using `pytest`. Beware that if you decide to name them with the prefix, they should be UTF-8 encoded.